# Score increment control in game

Tags: android

I have a game which I use a flag variable score to keep the score.

score is set to `int score = 0;`

Then increments each time something is correct : `score++;`

I then set this in the score TextView : `ScoreTV.setText(score);`

I am trying to have more control over the score by setting it to add on different scores depending on the amount of turns taken. I have tried to add in the TextView `ScoreTV.setText(score+10);` But this just makes it stick at 10 each time.

I would like to know if it is possible to add an amount I require each time instead of the score just incrementing each time by 1: `score++;`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScoreTV.setText(score+10);
```

Will always set the score text to 10 because the value of the score variable is staying at 0.  You need to update the value of score independently of displaying it.  Try this...

```
score = score + 10;
ScoreTV.setText(score);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can increment the score by any amount you desire by simply using the "add and assign" operator as follows:

```
score += X;
```

i.e.: To add 10 to the score use:

```
score += 10;
```

In terms of correctly displaying the score, it's probably easiest to update the score independently of the display. (i.e: Simply update the score as above and then use `ScoreTV.setText(score);`.)

Comment: @Raj score += 10; is short for score = score + 10; as score++; is short for score = score + 1;